# How to configure nginx for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, nginx

[image]My actions: I install only: nginx 1.10.1, php7 and mysql 5.6 on ubuntu 14.04.
php install: `sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv php7.0-opcache php7.0-soap php7.0-json php7.0-xml` 
I copy `sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/agestor.com`. 
In agestor.com paste:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {  
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {  
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name agestor.com;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/agestor.com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;
    include /var/www/agestor.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}

server {  
    listen 80;
    server_name agestor.com;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/agestor.com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;
    include /var/www/agestor.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

And include him: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/agestor.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` 
But not install magento 2.

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

error.log: `2016/06/21 14:21:35 [error] 13909#13909: *46 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 37.146.123.141, server: agestor.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "www.agestor.com"`
I set up my VPS on this article: [magento 2 for ubuntu 14.04](http://blog.analoglifestyle.com/magento-2-using-php7-nginx-and-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Check the nginx logs to see what the startup errors are

Comment: run `nginx -t` to see whats wrong

Comment: if you copy-paste configs then something is incomplete, some files or settings just missing.move all configuration, run nginx test

Comment: I open sudo nano /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock He was empty...

Comment: Maybe someone will write a short sequence of settings and actions? Please.

Comment: You can find information how to configure nginx for Magento in Magento DevDocs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Magento2 contains NGINX config `nginx.conf.sample` that can be included in you server section. Let's try with minimal configuration;

You need to modify `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domain.com` with the following content:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    # socket
    # server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # use tcp connection
    #  server  127.0.0.1:9000;
   
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-domen.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.my-domen.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 reuseport;
    server_name my-domen.com;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/my-domen.com/html;

   set $MAGE_MODE developer;
#    set $MAGE_MODE default;
#    set $MAGE_MODE production;

    include /var/www/my-domen.com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
}
```

and then add other settings do not relate to Magento

Comment: What have you added or changed in this answer? Can you clarify?

Comment: I meant please add to your answer :-)

Comment: the problem not in nginx config but in "copy-paste" issue, i think something is missing there, and you have to teach them to fix the issue, instead you offer him another copy-paste. this is the never ending story...

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Please write steps after install: nginx, php7, mysql. Maybe I made a mistake.

Comment: I showed in the issue at the top of the image and error logs.

Comment: Can you verify  that user  (configured in php-fpm - default www-data) have access to php files?

Comment: flame@55634:/var/www/agestor.com/html$ groups flame
flame : flame sudo www-data
flame@55634:/var/www/agestor.com/html$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data flame

Comment: I try your config.  sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "agestor.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful 
Error.log 2016/06/22 07:09:20 [warn] 29653#29653: conflicting server name "agestor.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Comment: Plese verify that listen  and server_name combination is unique. For example in redirect from www is not used domain without www

Comment: I try server_name www.agestor.com; url stay agestor.com, but page not open "File not found."

Comment: add error_log /tmp/n.log debug; after  server_name agestor.com; and  open your site and shown content of  /tmp/n.log file. If file is empty then problem not in nginx configuration or you have duplicate configuration for you domain

Comment: What do you think this is a good config?[exemple](https://github.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config/blob/master/magento2/sites-available/magento2.conf)

Answer (score 3):

you need to run `nginx -t` to see whats missing.

anyway i think you forgot to move other config files, we have installer for this `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config/master/m2_config_install.sh`

this will take all nginx configuration files from our repository and copy them to your nginx folder.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer... 2023

Example for **NGINX** configuration files for **Magento ver. 2.4.5**

File **main** configuration */etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        upstream fastcgi_backend {
            server unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

File configuration for **domain** */etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com*

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/private.key;

    server_name domain.com;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;

    location /blog {
       root /var/www/html;
       index index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;

       location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    include /var/www/html/nginx.conf;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

File configuration for service **sub-domain** */etc/nginx/sites-available/service.domain.com*

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/private.key;

    server_name service.domain.com;

    root /var/www/service;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```